What is the best approach to get one thread to suspend/resume another?
I need to create two threads in a dll project, one main and one menu. The main thread need to suspend and wakeup menu thread under certain conditions. The method I listed here is not desirable as Suspend/Resume can cause deadlock situation. So the question is how to properly making one thread to suspend/resume another thread?
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hModule,DWORD dw_reason,LPVOID lpReserved)
{
  switch (dw_reason)
  {
  case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    MainHandle=CreateThread(0, 0, MainThread, hModule, 0, &MainThreadID);
    MenuHandle=CreateThread(0, 0, MenuThread, hModule, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &MenuThreadID);
    break;
  case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    break;
  case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    break;
  case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    break;
  }
  return TRUE;
}

DWORD WINAPI MenuThread(LPVOID param) {
    ........; UI Updating Code Here
    return 0;    
}

DWORD WINAPI MainThread(LPVOID param) {
    ......; Main Logic Code Here
   if   (KeyPressed) {             
        ResumeThread(MenuHandle);
   }else{
        SuspendThread(MenuHandle);
   } 
    return 0;    
}


The use of SuspectThread and ResumeThread is frowned upon - if a suspended thread holds resources, it can cause deadlocks and/or hangs. I sometimes use events (manual or auto-reset) to activate or deactivate threads in these types of scenarios.

I was going to suggest that the "sleeping" thread wait on an event as well. And also note that CreateThread itself is likely frowned on, likely much better to use _beginthreadex.

Explore the Wait functions.

"I assume it is because the lack of authority in these thread handles" - you assume incorrectly. (Suspend|Resume)Thread() require the HANDLE to have the THREAD_SUSPEND_RESUME access right. The HANDLE returned by CreateThread() has THREAD_ALL_ACCESS access, which includes THREAD_SUSPEND_RESUME. So, if you are having a problem with (Suspend|Resume)Thread() then you are likely just using them incorrectly. That being said, you absolutely should not be using them AT ALL. Instead, use CreateEvent()/ResetEvent() with WaitForSingleObject(), or equivalent.

Suspension needs to be collabrative, otherwise race over shared resources can happen. If C++20 is an option, switch to std::jthread and sync with std::barrier or std::condition_variable. There's more to synchronization in std, but these 2 are primary candidates for multiple suspensions.

Surely it would be better to just disable/re-enable the menu control element?

At first glance it sounds a bit backwards to suspend a "menu thread", the common pattern most have is where you have an UI that runs on its own thread to be always responsive to the user,, then worker threads to handle various tasks.

Assuming you're not required to use the Windows API for thread creation, it's probably better to run with std::thread or std::jthread in this case, as mentioned in one of the comments. Condition variables are designed for cases such as this, and cause threads to sleep gracefully until certain conditions are met. The updated code would look something like this:
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

// Define these wherever makes sense for your program
static std::condition_variable key_condition;
static std::mutex mtx;

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hModule,DWORD dw_reason,LPVOID lpReserved)
{
  switch (dw_reason)
  {
  case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    MainHandle=std::jthread(&MainThread, hModule);
    MenuHandle=std::jthread(&MenuThread, hModule);
    break;
  case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    break;
  case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    break;
  case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    break;
  }
  return TRUE;
}

DWORD WINAPI MenuThread(LPVOID param) {
    // The function setting KeyPressed will also obtain this mutex
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        key_condition.wait(lock, [&KeyPressed](){return KeyPressed;});
    }
    ........; UI Updating Code Here
    return 0;    
}

DWORD WINAPI MainThread(LPVOID param) {
    ......; Main Logic Code Here
    key_condition.notify_one();
    return 0;    
}

Now this code probably won't run as-is, there will be other refactoring changes you would need to make. But it should get you started in the right direction.
The menu thread will launch and immediately acquire the mutex and check if KeyPressed is true (if you don't want it to immediately run you can always add another flag variable and set it true once you're ready for the thread to be "activated"). If KeyPressed is true, MenuThread will run, otherwise it will unlock the mutex, sleep, and wait for a corresponding call to notify_one(), at which point it will check the value of KeyPressed again. The mutex will be acquired again once KeyPressed is true and the thread wakes.
